# NodeJS Distribute Processing (Partition - Clustering)

Tags: node.js, redis, semaphore, distributed-computing, partition

I would like to ask for some advice regarding the distributed processing of a NodeJS application.

The process that I need to distribute is the manual attention of a chat service queues, so that I only make assignments when there are hours availability, agents available and the process is done in a single replica of the service.

At this point I am locking Redis to try to distribute the load, and ensure that only one replica is working on a process at a time. However I have been having problems with high Redis load, so I wanted to find an alternative for the need.

It occurred to me to do something similar to what faust (python) does on Kafka, assigning work partitions, so that when the service restarts an automatic redistribution of the work to be done is done.

I would like to know if you know of any bookstore that can help me with this purpose, or if not, could give me an idea.

Thank you for your attention and collaboration

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Redis Stream](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro)

It has the notion of **Consumer Groups** (A group of consumers each doing a portion of work), it's similar to Kafka.

You don't need a book for this, just reading the Redis website should get you started.